# Report Cross-Filter on Lookup . Looking for a standard solution

Tags: reporting, custom-object, lookup, cross-filter

the scenario is the following one:

- My client wants to be able to report his opportunities based on the Account Segmentation
- I cannot create new fields because we are in a system used by different countries, and the creation of a field on an object visible to global level required a lot of time

[image]

The Opportunity is a child of the Account.
The Segment is an independent object, the Account_Segment is a join object, that connects Account and Segment.

My idea was to create a report with ReportType "Account with Opportunities" and put a cross filter that point to the lookup "Segment" of the object Client Segment.

[image]

The idea was cool, but it doesn't work. I tried to write the id in a different way, and I also put directly the name of the Segment (parent object): But still it doesn't work.
The id is correct, the field is available for the filter. What am I missing?
Is this one a limit/bug of SF?

If it is not possible to fix the problem with a new field, could a formula field help in the Client Segment object?

[image]

I saw that for instance when I put the filter *segment different as ""*, some results are displayed, so that makes me think that maybe there is a way to use that field.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are filtering on the wrong field. Segment (API Name Segment__c ) is the field on the Account object. while you are entering the id of Segment record which is an independent object record hence it showing the blank report.

you can create the joint report

> account with the opportunity

> Account with the client segment

the second report type will have the required secondary master field.
then you can filter on it.

I believe this will resolve your issue!!!!

Comment: Hi @Shkhar, thank you for the suggestion, I explored the solution that you suggest to me.
But if I filter on the second report, the result will be that the first account shows the Account with blank space on the second report section, if the "client segment" of the segment that I choose is not a child of the account that appears in the first report.
I guess that the filter can only be done on the Account level.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339384&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Segment__c is the field on the Client Segment object that is pointing to the Segment (Segmentation on the picture). So it is the right field